# How to filter a string after a particular character in iOS?

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsscanner

I want to filter string after character '='. For eg if 8+9=17 My output should be 17. I can filter character before '=' using NSScanner, how to do its reverse??? I need a efficient way to do this without using componentsSeparatedByString or creating an array

Comment: `componentsSeparatedByString` is (in *my* opinion) one of the most often abused methods. Why create an array? Isn't `rangeOfString`+`substringFromIndex` much more straighforward? But SO answerers and readers seem to like it! - Sorry, I had to say this once.

Comment: Martin R is right, but I wasn't sure how rangeOfString option is better. I would recommend to accept @rmaddy's answer instead of mine, by pressing checkmark below the answer.

Comment: Can you explain why you are not comfortable with proposed solutions (e.g., using `componentsSeparatedByString`)?

Comment: It is quite inefficient when you just want one part of a string. The one I mark best answer describes this the best. And in my requirement i have a log like 8+9=+9-7=19 and I need to filter only 19 from the array of such logs.

Comment: Try this                                                          NSArray* foo = [@"10/04/2011" componentsSeparatedByString: @"/"];
NSString* day = [foo objectAtIndex: 0];

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Everyone seems to like to use `componentsSeparatedByString` but it is quite inefficient when you just want one part of a string.

Try this:

```
NSString *str = @"8+9=17";
NSRange equalRange = [str rangeOfString:@"=" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
if (equalRange.location != NSNotFound) {
    NSString *result = [str substringFromIndex:equalRange.location + equalRange.length];
    NSLog(@"The result = %@", result);
} else {
    NSLog(@"There is no = in the string");
}
```

Update:

Note - for this specific example, the difference in efficiencies is negligible if it is only being done once.

But in general, using `componentsSeparatedByString:` is going to scan the entire string looking for every occurrence of the delimiter. It then creates an array with all of the substrings. This is great when you need most of those substrings.

When you only need one part of a larger string, this is very wasteful. There is no need to scan the entire string. There is no need to create an array. There is no need to get all of the other substrings.

Comment: +1 as I already have a vague idea you are right. Could you bit explain the relative advantages? I am recommending OP to accept your answer rather than mine.

Comment: See my update for an explanation.

Answer (score 8):

```
NSArray * array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
if (array)
{
    NSString * desiredString = (NSString *)[array lastObject]; //or whichever the index
}
else
{
    NSLog(@""); //report error - = not found. Of array could somehow be not created.
}
```

**NOTE:**
Though this is very popular splitting solution, it is only worth trying whenever every substring separated by separator string is required. rmaddy's answer suggest better mechanism whenever the need is only to get small part of the string. Use that instead of this approach whenever only small part of the string is required.

Comment: This is a very inefficient way to get just one little piece of a larger string.

Comment: This is simple and effective LOC. Sure for +1!

Comment: check Array count then assign if ([array count]>1)
    {
        NSString * desiredString = (NSString *)[array objectAtIndex:1]; //or whichever the index

    }
    else
    {
      

        NSLog(@""); //report error - = not found. Of array could somehow be not created.
    }

Answer (score 5):

Try to use this one

```
        NSArray *arr = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
        if (arr.count > 0)
        {
            NSString * firstString = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString * secondString = [arr objectAtIndex:1];
            NSLog(@"First String %@",firstString);
            NSLog(@"Second String %@",secondString);
        }
```

**Output**

First String 8+9

Second String 17

Comment: This code will crash if the string does not have an `=` in it.

Comment: The first NSLog should be NSLog(@"First String %@",firstString);

Comment: @PradeepReddyKyp Thanks for your correction.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 NSString *a =@"4+6=10";
    NSLog(@"%@",[a componentsSeparatedByString:@"="])
```

;

```
 Log: Practice[7582:11303] (
        "4+6",
        10
    )
```